# Get array of string from array of array of string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of an array of strings like this.

```
const data =  [ ['a' , 'b'] , ['c' , 'd' , 'e'] , ['f'] ]
```

I want to convert it into an array of strings like this in javascript.

```
const data = [ 'a' , 'b' , 'c' , 'd' ]
```

Comment: What rules make `e` and `f` not be included? Also what have you tried and what research have you done?

Comment: `data.flat()` is what you're looking for...If you want array of strings...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the `array` you'll have to use `let` instead of `const`. This will do it.

```
let data =  [ ['a' , 'b'] , ['c' , 'd' , 'e'] , ['f'] ]
data = data.flat()
console.log(data)  //["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

Comment: Please flag duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Look at the docs for this `.flat()` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat

```js
const arr1 = [0, 1, 2, [3, 4]];

console.log(arr1.flat());
// expected output: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Though if you're going to modify the array, `const` isn't the way to declare the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat to convert this array

```js
var array =  [ ['a' , 'b'] , ['c' , 'd' , 'e'] , ['f'] ];
var UpdatedArray = [];


for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    UpdatedArray = UpdatedArray.concat(array[i]);
}

console.log(UpdatedArray);
```